# How do i get Windows 10 to appear in my grub menu, after a Fedora 35 reinstall, on my dual boot system?

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, fedora, grub2

My dual boot (Windows 10 and Fedora 35) Dell Precision 3541 has been running well for some time.

Recently, the Fedora 35 install became corrupted, so I reinstalled it from the same Live USB stick I used the first time around.

The box now booted directly into Fedora, so I installed grub2 with:

```
sudo dnf install shim os-prober efibootmgr grub2 grub2-efi
```

then ran:

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig
```

I now have a grub boot menu, but it does not have an option for Windows.

I assume I need to add an entry to my `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, which currently looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
```

Windows and Fedora were both installed as UEFI.

Here is my output from fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM049-2GH1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt 
Disk identifier: E492CDDF-2463-4E43-A2B7-EE91537847F2

Device         Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    1085439    1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2    1290240    1323007      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3    1323008  516952534  515629527 245.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  516954112  518438911    1484800   725M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  518440960  519921663    1480704   723M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  519921664  521150463    1228800   600M EFI System
/dev/sda7  521150464  523247615    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8  523247616 1953523711 1430276096   682G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/zram0: 8 GiB, 8589934592 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

and here is my output from lsblk -no UUID /dev/sda3:

```
E29CC86D9CC83E33
```

Is adding code to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` what I need to do here, and if so,
what should that code look like?

Many thanks in advance for your help with this.